# Poincare-Bendixson in a $2\times 2$ system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Show that the system

$x^{'} = x-y-x^{3}$ and $y^{'}=x+y-y^{3}$

Has a periodic solution using Poincare-Bendixson

I really have no idea how to apply this theorem i know that i need find an orbit and that is basically the hard part clearly 0,0 is a fixed point i want to remove it and then find a upper bound which should be all that difficult once x and y exceed 1 everything should get dragged inside of it. can i do this without converting to polar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some problems are simply set up to be more easily analyzed in polar coordinates. In particular, the natural way to find an orbit-containing region that is bounded away from the origin is to find a minimal radius for some orbit. You should try the change of variables
$$ \dot{r} = \frac{x \dot{x} + y \dot{y}}{r}, \quad \dot{\theta} = \frac{x \dot{y} - \dot{x} y}{r^2} $$
and see if you can show that if the initial radius has a certain range of values, then it can never exceed a certain amount and never reach $0$. You'll also need to show that there are no fixed points in this region. Then, by the theorem, there's a cycle.

Comment: so i do need to convert to polar can try and get away with root 2 as a bound then ^^