# The Poincare-Bendixson Theory in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show that the system 
$$
\begin{cases}
x'= y \\
y'= -x+y(1-x^{2}-y^{2})
\end{cases}
$$
has a unique stable limit cycle which is the w-limit set of every trajectory except the critical point at the origin.

I think I should start with computing $r'$, but I don't know what to do after that.

Comment: refer to a similar problem, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328051/poincare-bendixson-in-a-2-times-2-system?rq=1 hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$. Then the system of DEs becomes
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\dot{r}&=&r(1-r^2)\sin^2\theta,\\
\dot{\theta}&=&-1+(1-r^2)\sin\theta\cos\theta.
\end{array}\right.$$
Let $D$ be the region between two circles $C_1: r=\frac12$ and $C_2: r=\frac32$. Let $F=\{y,-x+y(1-x^2-y^2)\}$. Note that, $\dot{r}\ge0$ in $C_1$ and $\dot{r}\le0$ in $C_2$. So $F$ is radially out for the small circle and in for the big circle, namely, $F$ points outwards along $C_1$ and inwards along $C_2$. Clearly $F$ does not have equilibrium points in $D$ and $(0,0)$ is the only critical point of the system. By the Poincare-Bendixson theorem, there is a stable limit cycle for the system and the only closed trajectory.